# Controller in c# does not receive parameters from angular via POST

Tags: c#, angular13, asp.net-core-6.0

Form from Component HTML send this:

```
 <form [formGroup]="Denuncia" (ngSubmit)="guardarDatos()">
 <div class="form-group offset-md-1">
 <label>(*) Tipo de Denuncia&nbsp;</label>
 <select class="combobox" id="Tipo_Denuncia" formControlName="Tipo_Denuncia">
 <option value="">--Seleccione Opción--</option>
 <option [ngValue]="TipoDenuncia.cod_Tipo_Denuncia" *ngFor="let TipoDenuncia of 
 TiposDenuncia">{{TipoDenuncia.nombre}}</option>
 </select>
 </div>
 <input [disabled]="!Denuncia.valid" type="submit" value="Generar" class="btn btn- 
 success col-md-1 offset-md-1" />
 </div>
```

On Component.ts

```
    constructor(private denunciaservice: DenunciaService, private router: Router, 
    private modalService: NgbModal, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.Denuncia = this.formBuilder.group(
          {
            "Tipo_Denuncia": new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
          }
        );
      }
```

Method call service

```
    guardarDatos() {
        if (this.Denuncia.valid == true) {
       this.denunciaservice.agregarDenuncia(this.Denuncia.value).subscribe(data => { 
    
            if (data) {
              console.log(data);
              this.resultadoGuardadoModal = "ok";
    
            }
            else
              this.resultadoGuardadoModal = "Not Ok!";
          });
        }
      }
```

Service.ts:

```
        public agregarDenuncia(Denuncia: any): Observable<any>
          {
            var url = this.urlBase + 'api/Denuncia/guardarDenuncia/';
            return this.http.post(url,Denuncia);
          }
```

And declare class DenunciaDTO

Finally on the controller i dont recieve the parameter on the object DenunciaDTO

```
     [HttpPost]
            [Route("api/Denuncia/guardarDenuncia")] 
            public int guardarDenuncia([FromBody] DenunciaDTO oDenunciaDTO)
            {
                int rpta = 0;
                try
                {
                    using (M_VPSA_V3Context bd = new M_VPSA_V3Context())
                    {
                        using (var transaccion = new TransactionScope())
                        {
    oDenuncia.CodTipoDenuncia = int.Parse(oDenunciaCLS2.Tipo_Denuncia!);
                        } 
                    }
                    rpta = 1;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    rpta = 0;
                }
                return rpta;
            }
```

When execute this oDenunciaDTO is null on the controller. What Happened??

Answer (score 1):

Change `[FromBody]` to `[FromForm]`, and your issue will be fixed.

Comment: Tks, it works!!

Comment: @RomanSadowski Could you accept it as answer，tks